# Does pain tend to be more differentiated than pleasure?

Tags: nietzsche, good-and-evil, pain-and-pleasure

Does pain tend to be more differentiated than pleasure? Which is said to be open to more interpretations and variations, pleasure or pain?

See what Sade had to say about this sort of question, quoted by Brassier in *Nihil Unbound*

[image]

This is highly suggestive of pain being more differentiated. But that seems a a little quick. What would Nietzsche say, who, it is sometimes claimed, tried to reorient the human conception of pain? And surely, we recognize that the varieties of *happiness* are multifarious, that there is no one "good life"?

Comment: This seems like a question for psychologists, what is philosophical about it? You may what to ask on [CogSci SE with psychology tag](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology).

Comment: i think that a philosopher could answer this question far better than a psychologist, though one may be able to imagine an empirical answer.

Comment: As it is phrased, I can not imagine a *non*-empirical answer. You do not specify according to whom "pain tends to be more differentiated" or "open to more variations". So either it is answered based on psychological polls, or users just offer their personal opinions. Both are off-topic here. Could you edit the post to make some tangible connection with philosophy?

Comment: philosophers talk about the nature of pain and pleasure, i'm at a complete loss why you are sure that this question doesn't fit under "philosophy" @Conifold which isn't to ask for personal opinions, ofc

Comment: Then edit in names of philosophers you have in mind and/or philosophical aspects regarding which they talk about it. It is up to you to make your question specific and answerable, we can not guess what is on your mind.

Comment: @Conifold hm well all I can think of is Sade. i'll consider trying to save this question, which i still think has a very interesting answer. thanks for your time my friend!